# Make an ExpandableListView and Textview scroll together

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have this code xml layout that I am trying to implement in a round android wear watch. I want the `TextView` above the `ExpandableListView` to scroll with it rather than staying on the top and taking up space.

I tried using `ScrollView` with it rather than `RelativeLayout` (`ScrollView` in `RelativeLayout` and vice versa as well) but what that does is that the `LinearLayout` requires a set height for the `ExpandableListView` to show the list which is not possible as the list dynamically changes (so it can have a random number of group members) and if I use "`wrap_content`" it only shows one group at a time. Each group has 4 child members as well.

Can someone tell me how to make this layout suitable for me so that the `TextView` and the `ExpandableListAdapter` scroll together without having a set height for the `ExpandableListAdapter`?

round_activity_card_view_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jawad.wifihotspotfinder.CardViewLayout"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_round"
    android:background="#FF3C00"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewHeader"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/round_expandableListView"
                android:background="#FF3C00"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:longClickable="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into [addHeaderView(View v)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)). Create your `TextView` programmatically or inflate from XML and then add it to your `ExpandableListView` using that method.

The `TextView` should then scroll with your `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for showing me what to do, Alex. I had to come up with some way to do that which took ages but finally got it right. Thanks for the instructions which really helped me a lot! The code is used is given below:

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandable_header, expListView, false);
mLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
expListView.addHeaderView(mLayout);
```

Also the changed xml files:

expandable_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF3C00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expCardViewHeader"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#FF3C00"
        android:text="@string/no_results"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

round_activity_card_view_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jawad.wifihotspotfinder.CardViewLayout"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_round"
    android:background="#FF3C00"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF3C00"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/round_expandableListView"
            android:background="#FF3C00"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```